# NHibernate selecting from a many to many collection and use 'or' between different tables

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I would like NHibernate to generate the following SQL but I'm stuggling with the code below

```
SELECT * FROM [TCRM_Client] where (
 [ID] in (  
  SELECT B.ClientID FROM TCRM_Contact A,R_Client_Contact B
  WHERE A.ID = B.ContactID
  AND (
        A.Mobile LIKE 'KEYWORD%' OR A.Tel LIKE 'KEYWORD%'
      )  
  )
 OR Name LIKE '%KEYWORD%'
)



private void AddCriterion<T>(IQueryOver<T, T> query)
         where T : Client
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyWord))
    {
        var r1 = (Restrictions.On<Client>(x => x.Name)
          .IsLike("%" + keyWord + "%", MatchMode.Start));
        var profilequery = query.Left.JoinQueryOver<ClientContact>
          (o => o.ClientContactList)
          .Left.JoinQueryOver<Contact>(x => x.Contact).Where(o => o.ID != Guid.Empty);
        var r2 = Restrictions.On<Contact>(x => x.Tel)
          .IsLike("%" + keyWord + "%", MatchMode.Start) || 
          Restrictions.On<Contact>(x => x.Mobile)
          .IsLike("%" + keyWord + "%",MatchMode.Start);

        //A failed attempt
        //query.Add(r1)
        //profilequery.Add(r2);


        //Another failed attempt
        //query.RootCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Or(r1,r2));
    }
}
```

These code cannot works because of it is not use the keyword 'OR' between different tables currently.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT B.ClientID FROM TCRM_Contact A,R_Client_Contact B
  WHERE A.ID = B.ContactID and A.Mobile LIKE 'KEYWORD%'
  union all
  SELECT B.ClientID FROM TCRM_Contact A,R_Client_Contact B
  WHERE A.ID = B.ContactID and A.Tel LIKE 'KEYWORD%'
```

You can try to use this instead of .